# get property in laravel Session object

Tags: php, laravel, session, object

I'm trying to set `access_token` as header using middleware, I've been able to set my session and get session using

```
session(['key' => $con]); 
$request->session()->get('key');
```

```
{
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "expires_in":31536000,
    "access_token":"eyJ0eXKV1QiLCJhbGc",
    "refresh_token":"nTnUjx7xC6dXMTal2DqQDz8pfYc="
}
```

but I cant seems to get any property in the session object

```
$access = $request->session()->get('key');
$access->token_type //Trying to get property of non-object`enter code here`
```

Comment: What do you get if you `dd($access);`?

Comment: i got {"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":31536000,"access_token":"eyJ0eXKV1QiLCJhbGc","refresh_token":"nTnUjx7xC6dXMTal2DqQDz8pfYc="} as $access

Comment: Is `$con` a JSON string?

Comment: No, $con is an object. I've tried json_decode($access); //The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

Comment: What do you get if you do `dd(gettype($request->session()->get('key')));`. Also, where are you adding `$access = $request->session()->get('key');`?

Comment: dd(gettype($request->session()->get('key'))); is "string"

Comment: I'm also setting a Global Session Helper to an object and unable to retrieve properties.